# how to encode a url with urllib or urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I want a url like `example.com/page.html` to somthing like
`example.com/a$xDzf9D84qGBOeXkXNstw%3D%3D106`

Comment: What exactly do you mean? That doesn't look like base64 nor url-encoded string

Comment: Why? The former URL looks much prettier. Please explain your question a bit more.

Comment: I'm guessing a) he's foolishly looking for a means to map url path components to deterministic junk for reasons of (imagined) security by obscurity and b) we'll never hear back from freeman11

Comment: you might have asked better, like "how do i convert the urls into those unreadable urls containing many percent signs... and whose are still working as the original urls".. :) (in case i'm getting your answer well)

Answer (score 3):

In case you mean this:

```
  >>> import urllib, base64
  >>> urllib.quote_plus('example.com/page.html')
  'example.com%2Fpage.html'
  >>> base64.urlsafe_b64encode('example.com/page.html')
  'ZXhhbXBsZS5jb20vcGFnZS5odG1s'
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably wanted something like this:

```
>>> url = 'stackoverflow.com/questions/2841879/how-to-encode-a-url-with-urllib-or-urllib2'
>>> host, path = url.split('/', 1)
>>> path_mangled = ''.join(['%%%02x' % ord(x) if x not in '/?&' else x for x in path])
>>> url_mangled = '/'.join([host, path_mangled])
>>> url_mangled
'stackoverflow.com/%71%75%65%73%74%69%6f%6e%73/%32%38%34%31%38%37%39/%68%6f%77%2d%74%6f%2d%65%6e%63%6f%64%65%2d%61%2d%75%72%6c%2d%77%69%74%68%2d%75%72%6c%6c%69%62%2d%6f%72%2d%75%72%6c%6c%69%62%32'
```

(note that for full urls with scheme (http://...), you you have to change the second line)

Comment: This question should have more upvotes. It's clearly what the OP wanted, and it's quite helpful. Yet the mostly useless answer above has far more upvotes. Hmm...